# CSS vs XAML Measurements

Tags: css, xaml, uwp

I am using `VisualState`s in my XAML to trigger UI changes at 700pt. I also have a CSS file (applied to a `WebView` that is taking up the full page width) that is supposed to change the font size at 700pt. My XAML is:

```
<AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="700"/>
```

And the CSS is:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 700pt)
```

However, the XAML triggers a good deal sooner than the CSS. I can't figure out why they wouldn't trigger at the same time.

Comment: While I'm not too familiar with the pt unit on either platform, `MinWindowWidth` and other measurements in UWP XAML are measured in effective pixels (epx), not typographic points (pt), and AFAIK the pt unit in CSS is actually based on a typographic point. The CSS pixel unit is px. That could be it. Change your media query to `only screen and (min-width: 700px)` and see if it works.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah ok I thought UWP XAML measures in pts. Unfortunately px still does the same thing.

Comment: When exactly does the XAML trigger (and likewise for the CSS)?

Comment: @BoltClock What do you mean by "when"? Do you mean at what width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xaml in UWP works with effective pixels https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn958435.aspx#designing_with_effective_pixels while your css probably works with regular ones. You'll need to convert between the two.

More on effective pixels math here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-63